# Why do most of my MP3s show up as "unknown artist/album" in the Zune Software?

Tags: mp3, zune, id3, windows-phone, zune-software

Just got myself a Windows Phone 7 (WP7) and am trying to sync my MP3s from my computer to my WP7 (via the Zune) feature. So I downloaded the Zune software and pointed it to my MP3 folder and it found all of my MP3s.

The problem I'm having is that the majority of the songs show up as "unknown artist" / "unknown album", which is confusing because they all have ID3 tags. Winamp has no trouble picking up these tags.

What do I need to do to get the Zune Software to work properly?

Answer (score 4):

Windows 7 and WP7 cannot handle `ID3v2 version 2.4`.

Make sure they have `ID3v2` at most `2.3` or `ID3v1` tag.

Comment: Tagscanner (http://www.xdlab.ru/en/index.htm) would be a good free app to write all tags to an older format.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue also recently and was able to fix it today by editing the tags.

I downloaded [Mp3Tag](http://mp3tag.de/en/download.html) and used it to set values for the following tags, which fixed my issue:

- Artist
- Album
- AlbumArtist
- AlbumArtistSort
- ArtistSort

I don't use the album feature so I set ALL of the above fields to be the Artist...so if Jay Z made the song then the songs have Jay Z as the album, artist, etc.

I deleted everything from my collection in Zune, fixed the tags and re-synced. I had originally tried to fix it by filling in values for artist, album and albumartist but it didn't work. It looks like the trick was setting the "sort" tags for some reason.